# API Query, JSON, Dictionary

Tags: json, python-2.7, api, dictionary

I am using JSON for the FAA's API. For my below code, I am trying to print the get data from inside the "airport_response" variable into a dictionary called "airport_data". Then I just want to print out the keys called airport_data_keys. Currently, I am getting an incorrect value the sequence element #0 has length 128 but 2 is required. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import json
import requests
url_parameters = {}
url_parameters["format"] = "json"
base_url = 'http://services.faa.gov/airport/status/'
airport = 'DTW'
airport_response = requests.get(base_url + airport, params = url_parameters)
airport_data = airport_response.json() 
airport_data = dict(airport_response)
for k, v in airport_data.items():
    k = airport_data_keys
    print airport_data_keys
```

current output:

status
city
name
IATA
ICAO
state
delay
weather

desired output: [u'status', u'ICAO', u'name', u'city', u'IATA', u'delay', u'state', u'weather']

Comment: Shouldn't you call `dict(..)` on `airport_data` instead of `airport_response`? Now it will see the entire response string as a single item and since a dictionary needs key/value, it will error.

Answer (score 0):

your `dict()` shouldn't be used with the `response`, but with the `json` of it, so using `dict(airport_response)` leads to an error you should use `airport_data` instead like `airport_data = dict(airport_data)`. Here's an example of what you want:

```
import json
import requests

url_parameters = {
    "format": "json"
}

base_url = 'http://services.faa.gov/airport/status/'
airport = 'DTW'

airport_response = requests.get(base_url + airport, params=url_parameters)
airport_data = airport_response.json()
airport_data = dict(airport_data)

airport_data_keys = []
for key, value in airport_data.items():
  airport_data_keys.append(key)

print airport_data_keys
```

Comment: Great that worked! One last thing if I want the keys to then print in a list in Unicode, how would I execute that?I tried print airport_data_keys('utf8') but it returned the error TypeError: 'Unicode' object is not callable.

Comment: @SammySmith yeh that helped a little, I updated my code too. What you need is too append each key to a list.